# registration button stopped working on access database

Tags: c#, winforms

it worked for one time and then suddenly stopped responding
I used main != null to get the database from the other form and to check if the textboxes are empty
OleDb usage is forbidden in my assignment
also nRow is for the rows in my reg Table

```
Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
            if (main != null)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text))
                {
                    DataRow nRow = main.mask4DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    int rc = main.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;

                    nRow[0] = rc;
                    nRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
                    nRow[2] = textBox2.Text;

                    main.mask4DataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Add(nRow);
                    main.regTableAdapter.Update(main.mask4DataSet.reg);
                    main.mask4DataSet.Tables[1].AcceptChanges();
                    main.dataGridView1.Refresh();

                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    textBox3.Text = "";

                    MessageBox.Show("Success", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    Form1 s = new Form1();
                    s.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Fill in each box please!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
```

i tried to change Tables[1] but that didnt help
i feel devastated